# Zoom into div on page load with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Bit of a strange issue but I couldn't find anything about this on Google. I have a scene I'd like to zoom into when the page loads.

Imagine the below image is 100% `window` width on page load, then after a delay the window zooms in so the monitor in the scene is 100% of the browser window. and the iframe is what you now see.

Does this make sense?

I'm unsure of the best way to do this, I tried to use `transform` property with scale but I've had no luck and I'm unsure how this would render the iframe? would the contents also scale?

http://jsfiddle.net/LLmaP/1/

[image]

Comment: Try like this, create a class for your transform an when the dom is ready add that class to the .page. Like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/LLmaP/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LLmaP/18/

```
$('.monitor').load(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('.page').addClass('fullscreen');
}, 1000);
});
```

but you have to set your cubic-bezier to make the background-size and the iframe height agree.
this website can help you

http://cubic-bezier.com/